# Angular: get data from different REST end points

Tags: angular, rest

I'm making a small POC app in angular.
I have to get data from different REST-end points for example

- server1.com/stillAlive
- server2.com/stillAlive

App is running on localhost, so I have to create `proxy.con` in angular
like this way:

```
{
    "/server1": {
        "target": "http://server1.com:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": "true"
    }
}
```

If I set only one proxy config like bellow - everything works fine..

But if I want to add `server2.com` into my `proxy.config` I get `CORS` (cars errors :D
) errors again

```
{
    "/server1": {
        "target": "http://server1.com:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": "true"
    },
    "/server2": {
        "target": "http://server2.com:4000",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": "true"
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem ?

I'm sure the problem is in front of monitor, but I can't find any decision.

Comment: you mean CORS error?

Comment: CORS errors occur because of missing response headers. This is a server-side issue on your server2

Comment: proxy code looks correct. make sure you really are use it. That you are calling /server1/stillAlive and /server2/stillAlive and hitting the local proxy

Comment: on second thoughts, why you use string for "changeOrigin": "true"? String true should evaluate to boolean true, but better be explicit,

Comment: "true" was not right, i made a typo in a question.

Comment: the problem is solved. configuration was changed to:
`
{
    "/server1": {
        "target": "http://server1.com:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite":{
                     "^/server1/":"/"
         }
    },
    "/server2": {
        "target": "http://server2.com:4000",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": "true"
        "pathRewrite":{
                     "^/server2/":"/"
          }
    }
}
`
here the solution :
angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server